# How to override existing plugin?

Tags: 8, plugins

Considering `Drupal\search_api\Plugin\views\query\SearchApiQuery` class, I want to override `shouldAbort()` method there.

I have tried to create a new plugin class in my custom mod:

```
namespace Drupal\my_mod\Plugin\views\query;

use Drupal\search_api\Plugin\views\query\SearchApiQuery;

/**
 * Defines a Views query class for searching on Search API indexes.
 *
 * @ViewsQuery(
 *   id = "search_api_query",
 *   title = @Translation("Search API Query"),
 *   help = @Translation("The query will be generated and run using the Search API.")
 * )
 */
class MymodSearchApiQuery extends SearchApiQuery {

  /**
   * @inheritdoc
   */
  public function shouldAbort() {
    //do something fancy
  }
}
```

But it seems to not work. How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the suggestion by @googletorp, you should use [hook_views_plugins_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_plugins_query_alter/8.2.x)().  You simply update the plugin class with your own that overrides it.

```
function my_mod_views_plugins_query_alter(array &$plugins) {
  $plugins['search_api_query']['class'] = 'Drupal\my_mod\Plugin\views\query\MymodSearchApiQuery';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do, is to make views use your class instead of the the one solr module provides. Defining your own plugin wont help.

Instead you can use `hook_views_plugins_query_alter` to specify the plugin class.